# calculationg the bottom from the bottom of a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to get the bottom value from the bottom of a div . but in the console log i am getting 2 values one after another.First one is the bottom value and second one is  1051.1666870117188 .But i only want first one . Why i am getting such kind of problem . My code is

```
function get_bottom(){
        $elem1 = $('.your-cart');   
        var bottom = $(document).height() - ($elem1.offset().top + $elem1.height());

        console.log(bottom);
}

$(document).scroll(get_bottom);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it should give you what you want

```
 var bottom = $('#bottom').position().top+$('#bottom').outerHeight(true)
```